# Can you call a Cloud Run app from inside a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'd like to call a Cloud Run app from inside a Cloud Function multiple times, given some logic. I've googled this quite a lot and don't find good solutions. Is this supported?

I've seen the [Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/workflows) Tutorials, but AFAIK they are meant to pass messages in series between different GPC services. My Cloud Function runs on a schedule every minute and it would only need to call the Cloud Run app a few times per day given some event. I've thought about having the entire app run in Cloud Run instead of the Cloud function. However, I think having it all in Cloud Run would be more expensive than running the Cloud function.

Comment: Yes, Cloud Functions can call a Cloud Run application. What have you tried and what is the problem? Questions regarding pricing would need details and in general, is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Use Google's pricing calculator to analyze costs.

Comment: How can they be called? This is not documented or with examples anywhere obvious. Answers like this are not constructive. Link an example, give an example, etc. Do you know how many answers I give in subjects of my expertise that seem too simple to me? Many!

Comment: I did not post an answer, I offered a comment. This link might help you: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service Please read these links as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Cloud Functions, like Cloud Run, expose API. So, if you want to call something deployed on Cloud Run, you need to expose it behind an webserver and call that API in your Cloud Functions. @JohnHanley is right, I also don't really understand what is your blocker

Answer (score 1):

I went through your question, I have an alternative in my mind if you agree to the solution. You can use  [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)  to securely trigger a Cloud Run service asynchronously on a schedule.

- You need to create a service account to associate with Cloud
  Scheduler, and give that service account the permission to invoke
  your Cloud Run service, i.e. Cloud Run invoker (You can use an
  existing service account to represent Cloud Scheduler, or you can
  create a new one for that matter)
- Next, you have to create a Cloud Scheduler job that invokes your
  service at specified times. Specify the frequency, or job interval,
  at which the job is to run, using a configuration string. Specify the
  fully qualified URL of your Cloud Run service, for example
  https://myservice-abcdef-uc.a.run.app The job will send requests to
  this URL.
- Next, specify the HTTP method: the method must match what your
  previously deployed Cloud Run service is expecting. When you deploy
  the service using Cloud Scheduler, make sure you do not allow
  unauthenticated invocations. Please go through this
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) for details and try to implement the steps.

Back to your question, yes it's possible to call your Cloud Run service from inside Cloud Functions.  Here, your [Cloud Run service calls from another backend service](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) i.e. Cloud Functions directly( synchronously) over HTTP, using its endpoint URL. For this use case, you should make sure that each service is only able to make requests to specific services.
Go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) suggested by @John Hanley as it provides you with the steps you need to follow.

Comment: Thanks @Priyashree. For the alternate you posted, I do have separate use cases where I could do that. For the specific use case which made me post the question, the call to the Cloud Run would be made inside the Cloud function but instead of a schedule it needs to be based on an event. I'm looking deeper into the docs that John suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Math. Your question is good and I hope you find the answer soon.